# ADO.NET Entity-Database Application on Client Computer

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, deployment

So i'm currently studying for my C# certification exam, and i'm working on use of data, this involved ADO.NET Entities and using them to connect and communicate with a database (that is embedded in the application) and it's models that are created. I've created a relatively small and simple application based on the examples in the textbook.

However it occurred to me, what would happen if I were to try and deploy and application that has Entity Framework usage to a client computer (in-case, i used it in the future and needed to know how to make it work as it should). To my surprise it crashed, i've got a single datagrid which is binding data from a database when the application is first loaded. So i'm guessing there's some extra work to be done than just zipping up the files or doing a one-click deployment.

I do believe the computer i'm testing on has the appropriate .net framework.. (i'm currently checking this now).. but if it's not this, feel free to give your input ^.^

Below i've included the code of my example-test application

Employee Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
   class Employee
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string City { get; set; }
       public string State { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Main Window:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoStuff();
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee()
            {
                ID = 1,
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Smith",
                City = "Havertown",
                State = "PA"
            },
            new Employee()
            {
                ID = 2,
                FirstName = "Jane",
                LastName = "Doe",
                City = "Ewing",
                State = "NJ"
            },
            new Employee()
            {
                ID = 3,
                FirstName = "Jack",
                LastName = "Jones",
                City = "Fort Washington",
                State = "PA"
            }
        };

        var employeesByState = from e in employees
                                group e by e.State;

        using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            foreach (var employeeGroup in employeesByState)
            {
                foreach (var employee in employeeGroup)
                {
                    Stuff st = new Stuff()
                    {
                        ID = employee.ID,
                        FirstName = employee.FirstName,
                        LastName = employee.LastName,
                    };
                    db.Stuffs.Add(st);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    var result = (from c in db.Stuffs
                                 select c).ToList();
                    dtgResults.ItemsSource = result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i'm pretty sure i'm missing some essential requirement here since it crashes when its opening on a different computer. Even when using one-click deployment which I thought downloads and installs any requirements for the application.

If anyone could help me understand what i'm missing or understanding incorrectly that'd be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet.. I'll post this..

You should make sure that the other computers running the application have access to the database stated in the connection string configured on DatabaseEntities.

Comment: Ooh, my mistake.. I forgot to mention the database is embedded (fixed that now) BUT i'll make sure the connection string to the database is what it should be :) and not, for example navigating through the file system on my original machine

Comment: You should add a try-catch block just to be sure of what really is the problem. Perhaps you should start debugging the DoStuff() method